# MongoDB: how to get document with specific propety deep inside the object structure?

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I get MongoDB-document with **"test": NumberInt(1000)** property from RockMongo and from PHP?

I tried something alike to **{"items": {"test": 1000}}**, but

> No records is found.

Sample of Mongo collection:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("xxx"),
   "items": {
     "0": {
       "0": {
         "test": NumberInt(1000)
        }
      },
       "1": {
         "test": NumberInt(2000)
        },
    },
},
{
   "_id": ObjectId("yyy"),
   "items": {
     "0": {
       "0": {
         "test": NumberInt(3000)
        }
      },
       "1": {
         "test": NumberInt(4000)
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: In your sample `"items"` is object. May be it array?

Comment: There isn't a query that will work given the structure you've shown. It looks like you're not saving the `items` as an array. If that's intentional, then the query will not work as the subdocument's field names aren't known. You should see `"items": [ { "test" : NumberInt(1000) }]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.coll.find( { 'items.test': 1000 } )
```

and assure that `items` is an `array` and not an `object`.